# Is there a generic way to say "weekday" without the concept of "work/business/school day"?

Tags: translation, word-choice, word-requests

The most common translation of weekday is: 工作日

Google Translate suggests 工作日 and 平常日 for weekday.

Is 平常日 commonly used?

How would a native speaker normally say weekday?

Would it be odd for a young child use 工作日 as weekday? Would a be more normal for a child to use 学习日? What about during school holidays?

Comment: 平常日 can be shortened to 常日. For children, weekday is school day 上学日

Comment: I never hear"平常日" in neither conversation nor written material. "工作日" is the most direct translation to "weekday".  If it for student group, I(southern Chinese) would just use"....上学时"

Answer (score 3):

In fact we usually say 平日 as weekday, but more frequent we just say 周一到周五. Maybe it is because we just distinguish weekend is 周末,and every weekday is regarded as a normal day.

During the holiday, children usually have no sense of days(LOL,at least me), so they just know today is 周几,like 周一 or 周五.

I'm new here, hope my answer can help you.

Answer (score 3):

**周中** as opposed to *周末*

**ABC** defines it as:

> noun
>
> midweek

You could say something like：

周中上班，周末休息
Work on weekdays and have weekends off

Answer (score 2):

1. 周内：from Monday to Friday
2. 周末：Saturday & Sunday
3. 工作日、平日：workday
4. 非工作日、法定节假日、节假日、假日：non-workday, holiday

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there may be regional differences. The common words I use is 平时 for weekday, but there are many words that mean weekend such as 周末，礼拜天，周六日，休息天. I think it is because we all look forward to weekend, but not weekday.

Answer (score 1):

工作日 means workdays;
周内 and 平日 are seldom used, so if you use them some people might not get what you mean. 平日 may be confused with its other meaning "usually" as well.
From my experience, people usually use 非周末 when they want to say weekdays in China. It literally translates to "non-weekend".